# Nested integration for incomplete convolution of gauss densities

Tags: r, nested, convolution

Let `g(x) = 1/(2*pi) exp ( - x^2 / 2)` be the density of the normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. In some calculation on paper appeared integrals of the form

[image]

where c>0 is a positive number.

Since I could not evaluate this by hand, I had the idea to approximate and plot it. I tried this in R, because R provides the dnorm function and a function to do integrals.

You see that I need to integrate numerically n times, where n shall be chosed by the call of a plot function. My code has an for-loop to create those "incomplete" convolutions iterativly.

For example even with n=3 and c=1 this gives me an error. n=2 (thus it's one integration) works.

```
N = 3

ngauss <- function(x) dnorm(x , mean = 0, sd = 1)

convoluts <- list()
convoluts[[1]] <- ngauss

for (i in 2:N) {

 h <- function(y) {
   g <- function(z) {ngauss(y-z)*convoluts[[i-1]](z)}
   return(integrate(g, lower = -1, upper = 1)$value)
 }
 h <- Vectorize(h)

 convoluts[[i]] <- h

}

convoluts[[3]](0)
```

What I get is:

> Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
>   options(expressions=)?

I understand that this is a hard computation, but for "small" n something similar should possible.

Maybe someone can help me to fix my code or provide a recommendation how I can implement this in a better way. Another language that is more appropriate for this would be also okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue appears to be in how `integrate` deals with variables in different environments. In particular, it doesn't really deal with `i` correctly in each iteration. Instead using

```
  h <- evalq(function(y) {
    g <- function(z) {ngauss(y - z) * convoluts[[i - 1]](z)}
    integrate(g, lower = -1, upper = 1)$value
  }, list(i = i))
```

does the job and, say, setting `N <- 6` quickly gives

```
convoluts[[N]](0)
# [1] 0.03423872
```

As your integration is simply the pdf of a sum of `N` independent standard normals (which then follows N(0, N)), we may also verify this approach by setting `lower = -Inf` and `upper = Inf`. Then with `N <- 4` we have

```
dnorm(0, sd = sqrt(N))
# [1] 0.1994711
convoluts[[N]](0)
# [1] 0.1994711
```

So, for practical purposes, when `c = Inf`, you are way better off using `dnorm` rather than manual computations.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. I implemented your code, and, at least, I get no error anymore. It seems to work.
Of course I am not only interested in evaluating convoluts[[i]] at zero, but to plot it over the whole real line.
If c = Inf of course I could better use the semigroup property of normaldistribution in regard to convolution. By iterated convolution the mass flows out of every compact set.

But the crucial point here is especially that we don't integrate the convolution over the whole real line. There could be a change of behaviour in regard to this loss of concentration

Comment: Honestly, I guess now this computation won't really help me . Even for ´N<-6´ this takes way too long

Comment: @Falrach, possibly you have already looked into this, but for a general `c` we have a sum of symmetrically truncated normal random variables, so possibly https://www.jstor.org/stable/2236545 or some other paper can provide a good approximation.

Comment: in fact I have not looked into this. This notions are related to my problem I think, but my integral corresponds more to the case of truncation after every convolution than truncation before the convolution as in this  paper. But I think the notion of truncated random variables will help me to figure out if there is already something related to my question out there.